# What's the fastest Ruby on Rails setup for Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, installation

I have InstantRails installed along with WeBrick and sqlite3.

What exactly do I type in the Windows cmd console to setup a db called 'development' and to get the entire things running?

This is my *#&*%^# 4th day of installation. I can get everything running on my localhost EXCEPT setup my db. I'm not a programmer so if you have a good url for beginner tutorials that would be great.

Please tell me exactly what I need to type in the cmd console (or what console I need) to make my db hold the information.

I was typing $ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 to (boot up?) the db.

Then I typed:  CREATE TABLES (code)

Note - I already tried rake db:migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rake db:migrate  (assumimg you have at least 1 migration created ) .  The db should be created automatically.

Comment: do you get an error? if so what is it?  could you post your config/database.yml file? And do you have at least 1 migration created?  Also a good place to look would be logs/development.log for any errors...

Comment: ok that looks fine, any errors when you run the rake db:migrate command?  even without a migration it should create the db and create the schema_migrations table

Comment: I don't even know what a migration is. lol Sorry I didn't get to that part in the book yet. I looked at the logs/dev.log and only see 4 things that look like GET but I have no idea what the other information means.

Comment: When I type in the rake db:migrate this happens:
No Rakefile found (looking for:rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.db, Rakefile.rb)
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2377:in 'raw_load_rakefile'

Comment: are you running rake db:migrate in the root of your rails_app? and in that directory do you see a file called Rakefile?

Comment: you can try following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html  it should translate to windows (assuming you have rails, and the like installed which it seems that you do.)

Comment: Yea, I see a file called Rakefile. It's in the InstantRails in the folder of the app I'm trying to build.
-I have read that getting_started guide and it's way too advanced. They designed it for developers not designers. I'm lost when I start at 3.1

Comment: when you create a model, scaffold, etc..  It will create a migration file, which is a piece of ruby that tells how to build the database table to hold the data.  Don't worry if you don't have one yet, they aren't needed to run rake db:create or rake db:migrate.  But the fact that it cannot find the rake file, indicates to me that either you are not in the correct directory, or something got messed with either the rails_app in the directory or rake itself. I don't actually use windows, but have helped enough devs in our user group get rails setup on it...

Comment: Ok. Yes it could have got broke or could be in the wrong folder. Should I just delete everything and reinstall to ensure the correct paths and information. What you're saying does make sense to me. :) - I actually use to have it in a main folder called Ruby1 but deleted that and made Ruby.

Comment: My development.sqlite3 is empty too, if that matters.

Comment: hmm I not sure how instantrails works, in looking at the webpage it appears to be installing apache and mysql as well?  you should have a rakefile in the root of your directory? not in the instant rails directory.  If you would like you can try the installer a friend of mine built (and I helped debug)  http://edwardprevost.info/Blog/2010/06/19/winror-win-roar/  That will install ruby/rails and a text editor, and get you basically up and running. Sorry I can't help more with instant rails..

Comment: I would delete and start over.  Just get up a cmd prompt, and assuming the installer put rails in your path just create a directory to store you projects in (c:\railsprojects for example). then cd \railsprojects ;  rails test_app ; cd test_app; rake db:migrate

Comment: also see the first answer here...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows

Comment: Ok. My rakefile is in my folder of my app that's inside of InstantRails. I appreciate your help and would give you an arrow up but my Reputation is too low to do that. Thanks!