# How to start Ruby on Rails in windows 8?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, windows-8, rubygems

I am new one for Ruby on Rails.

Please tell the requirements for Ruby on Rails.

I am using windows 8 (64bit) operating system.

And tell which SDK is suitable for RoR in windows8.

Comment: VirtualBox and an Ubuntu VM... I know you *want* to do it on Windows, but so much (loads of Gems and libraries...) just don't work

Answer (score 2):

The ruby/rails/rubyinstaller has many bugs in Windows 8. Today still the best choice, but:

- you cannot install Ruby 2.0 in Windows 8 - it's not compatible with Rails 4 in Windows 8. You need to install 1.9.3 in order to use Rails 4 (and you probally will waste some time until realize this because there's no sign of this and it's even make sense)
- if you don't install Ruby in the exactly folder as is suggested, (e.g.: if you install in something like "d:\my apps\ruby"), it won't work, because the installer have trouble dealing with special characters, with whitespaces in the path, with more than 8 characters in the folder name (reminds me the old ms-dos), and I guess that some lines in the source-code has this default path explicitly written.
- if you don't install the dev-kit manually via command-line, it won't work.
- even that you have a 64bits OS you need to install the 32bits version of Devkit compiled in 32bits - at least now they warn this in the main page (3 months ago you need to discover this in the hard way).
- don't forget to ALWAYS call devkitvars.bar before the first Rails/gem command in the cmd
- yes, installing gems will generate "lib" errors - there's nothing that you can do, just ignore them
- finally, Windows 8 Javascript it's incompatible with Rails 4 - you need to change the runtimes.rb of "execjs" gem. The bugged line is the "JScript = ExternalRuntime.new ...". You need to remove the "//U" of ":command" and change the ":encoding" from "UTF-16LE" to "UTF-8".

I made a video explaining how to install Rails 4 in Windows 8. It's in portuguese, but I believe that you can follow what it's on screen:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPM9nwUQqZ0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any SDK. Install ruby itself:

http://rubyinstaller.org/

This will also install RubyGems (which is the dependency manager) and finally install Rails using RubyGems:

```
gem install rails
```

And you're good to go!

Comment: gem install rails is error                                              This error message come                                          C:\Windows\System32>gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belon
gs_to.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/book_
icon.gif, skipping

Comment: That is a known bug with Rdoc and Ruby 2.0, it's just an error with the documentation. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Remember to install the devkit as well: very important to be able to build native gems.

Answer (score 0):

Refer Link : [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Link One : [Install ROR in Windows 8](http://www.racap.net/2012/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-windows.html)

Link Two : [ROR for Windows 8](http://ngeor.net/2013/04/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows-8/)

Avoid windows as your development server because windows does not have to much library support for Rails application.

Playing at Ubuntu with Rails is like driving Ferrari .... I am agree with @Pavling suggestion about VM having Ubuntu12.04 LTS. I am also using the same way.

[Limitations In Running Rails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you can track down an old version of instant rails...you may be ok!  It seems to be somewhat self-contained and builds apps within its own little world! Unfortunately it has Ruby version 187, Instant Rails 2.0   It seems to work ok!