# Ruby 2 and Rails 3 running on windows server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, windows-server, ruby-2.0

I haven't tried yet, but I would like to have a good information background before begin.

I must run a Rails application on a Windows server (I think 2008),I know that there is other better solutions, but the client has this server's type.

I think that the problem can be solved in one of these four manners (maybe more?):

1. Running Apache/Ngnix as a service
2. Running directly from the OS
3. Running as virtualization
4. Running on a different partition (e.g. installing for example Ubuntu)

I have read tons of post but without finding a good solution (for Rails 3 and Ruby 2 I have find anything).

Which solution you suggest me? Which one is more stable and performant?
Any documentation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ruby on rails its better to run it on linux than windows , on windows you will face a lot of problems like when you going to install gems , best thing is to install a vmware on your windows machine , then run Ubuntu or any linux distro you like through vmware, also you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows?rq=1) to know more

Comment: but with virtualization you lose a lot in terms of performance, the server must running 2 OS in the same time that is weighter. I know that Windows is not the best solution, but (for the moment) I haven't alternative...

Comment: i have updated my answer , and if you dont need to use vmware , so you may install a linux distro as dual boot with windows

Comment: just like i did , installed a linux distro on a partition and to develop on rails 4 months ago and i still have windows on my hard disk also.

Comment: as the qestion i have linked into my answer , you may find some gems causing errors when you run it on windows unlike linux or mac where everything is running perfect

Comment: +1 thanks for the answers, the link you gived me is a little old (2008 until 2011). Sorry for my "system" ignorance, but with a Distro you can run the 2 OS in parallels, or is one OR the other on the same time?

Comment: I am running on linux , if its a must to use windows for doing anything else so i restart my machine to boot into windows but i do this maybe one or two times every month , an because i can do linux is making you able to do what you was doing in windows and for the link above , it still the same for windows at this time for example: when you try to install sqlite3 gem on windows the default database for rails it causing errors

Comment: thanks @Dexter for the details, it's strange that Windows doesn't support completly a popular language like RoR...

Comment: you are welcome, and look in the other side , i think any opensource language its better to be on linux for more performance and stability and free applications for sure