# The rubyracer plugin installation issue for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing below issue while bundle install in Windows (64 bit)

Fetching therubyracer 0.12.3
Installing therubyracer 0.12.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20181026-14920-qxvukg.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you are following something which installs rails on windows manually you might run into many issues. There is lot of discussion why using ruby on rails on windows is bad idea. But the best way to install ROR on windows is using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en).

I would suggest if it is possible you can install Ubuntu on your machine or use Mac. Here are discussions on the topic you might find help full.

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-Ruby-on-Rails-on-Windows

[Limitations in running Ruby/Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows)