# docker ruby on rails windows server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to run/deploy a ruby on rails app on a windows server using docker? 
I am using windows server 2016 and have set up the docker engine. 
The ruby on rails app that i have has the following dependencies. 
Puma/sqlite. I am new to docker , but was unable to find specific examples to run on windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible - yes. Potential nightmare - yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But RoR and Windows are not a good friend. You can check this old question: [Limitations in running Ruby/Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows)

If you insist to run/deploy RoRr in windows, you should read this: [Ruby on Rails on Docker for Windows](https://github.com/spikewilliams/rails4windocker). It might give you some ideas how to run RoR on Windows although it was only for development.

As other suggest, you shouldn't deploy RoR on Windows for production.