# Trying to install Ruby on Rails on windows 10. Terminal doesn't run webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to start Ruby on Rails and I downloaded ruby and rails, following a tutorial and when I run the new rails command in the terminal it adds all its files but doesn't run webpacker and bundler like the videos do which wont allow me to run the program in VS code using the "bin/rails s". I am new to this so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
My terminal: Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
run  bundle binstubs bundler
rails  importmap:install
Tutorials terminal: Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
run  bundle binstubs bundler
rails  webpacker:install
webpacker is "importmap" on my terminal and I cant figure out the issue

Comment: Install ubunto via WSL2. This will let you follow along with linux based tutorials (which most are) and avoid tearing your hair out getting stuff to work in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting out with rails then I suggest you use dual-booting or WSL
there are a few reasons for its awful running rails on a windows machine
have a look at this
[Limitations in running Ruby/Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes back to this for answers, webpacker was an older wrapper than no longer exists in Rails 7.0.0(if i'm not mistaken). The new wrapper is importmap, hence my confusion.