# deploy ruby or rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anyway to run Ruby on Rails applications on a Windows box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494/is-there-anyway-to-run-ruby-on-rails-applications-on-a-windows-box)

I understand most rails deploys to *nix server environment. Here is what I can only find to deploy rails to windows article

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/

But it seems pretty old (2008 and before).

Is there new resource I can refer for deploying rails on on windows environments?

Thanks